# Invites vs Requests on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have noticed that some apps have a distinction between 'Invites from friends' vs 'Requests from friends'. I've read through the Facebook docs and have not been able to find anything that tells me how to designate requests to be listed as invites. Is this something that just happens automatically or is this something else that I need to call specifically? Thanks.

[image: Invites from friends]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [requests documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) (User to User requests section):

> The recipient is a friend of the sender and has not installed the app. This is considered an Invite.